# How to create object in Rust like in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, rust

I'm new to Rust, and I would like to know if it's possible to create serializable objects like we do in Java. For instance, my Java class looks like this:

```java
public class Obj implements Serializable {
    int objNo;
    String objName;
    
    public Obj (int objNo, String objName) {
        this.objNo = sushiNo;
        this.objName = objName;
    }
}
```

I am able to create and access the object in another function, like below:

```java
Obj obj1 = new Obj(objNo, objName);
System.out.println("Object" + objNo + ": " + objName);
```

How do I translate this serializable/deserializable Java object into Rust and be able to access it? If it is not possible to create something like this, are there any alternatives?

I've read about struct and Serde, but I don't know how to implement it because the syntax looks very confusing to me, which is why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Have you read the book's section on [using structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-00-structs.html)? To make them serializable, use [Serde](https://serde.rs/).

Comment: hi, thanks for the response! I've read about struct and Serde, but I don't know how to implement it because the syntax looks very confusing to me, so I was hoping someone could show me an example of how to implement it

Comment: The [front page of Serde](https://serde.rs/#data-structures) shows a pretty clear example. You will need to specify in what way the syntax is confusing you, or maybe portray an example of what you were trying to achieve and could not understand how to get to a solution.

Comment: ok, will take note of that. thanks!

Comment: I just wanna add that Rust doesn't actually work as usual OO languages. There's neither "class" nor "object" strictly speaking, no inheritance, no casting. A way you can understand it is you can "link" a function to a type, and access it through any variable of this type. (Yes, you can add methods to integers, enums, and everything else.) And to allow generic code, there are traits that tell "any type implementing the trait have these methods". So for serializing, you need to have a type that implements the trait serializable (and you can implement it for the type if needed) and use the trait

Comment: @Naeio Thank you for that neat summary of Rust versus object-oriented programming. I’ve been looking for just such a thing, to satisfy my curiosity about Rust.

Comment: @BasilBourque No problem! I understand Rust can be puzzling for people coming from more conventional OO languages. Stack Overflow is not the best place to find people to help understand, you can go instead to the subreddit r/rust. Maybe you'll find me over there ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps, here is a trivial example which serialises some structs to a json string then deserialises this json string in order to recreate the equivalent structs.
But if you are not familiar with the basic elements of the Rust language, this will not be very helpful.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Stat {
    name: String,
    values: Vec<f32>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let prepared_stats = vec![
        Stat {
            name: "age".to_owned(),
            values: vec![37.0, 51.0, 46.0, 28.0],
        },
        Stat {
            name: "BMI".to_owned(),
            values: vec![28.2, 21.3, 18.4, 20.4],
        },
    ];
    println!("prepared_stats:\n  {:?}", prepared_stats);
    let json_serialised_stats = serde_json::to_string(&prepared_stats)?;
    println!("json_serialised_stats:\n  {}", json_serialised_stats);
    let deserialised_stats =
        serde_json::from_str::<Vec<Stat>>(&json_serialised_stats)?;
    println!("deserialised_stats:\n  {:?}", deserialised_stats);
    Ok(())
}
/*
prepared_stats:
  [Stat { name: "age", values: [37.0, 51.0, 46.0, 28.0] }, Stat { name: "BMI", values: [28.2, 21.3, 18.4, 20.4] }]
json_serialised_stats:
  [{"name":"age","values":[37.0,51.0,46.0,28.0]},{"name":"BMI","values":[28.2,21.3,18.4,20.4]}]
deserialised_stats:
  [Stat { name: "age", values: [37.0, 51.0, 46.0, 28.0] }, Stat { name: "BMI", values: [28.2, 21.3, 18.4, 20.4] }]
*/
```

In `Cargo.toml`

```rust
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
```